# Friendly URLs with sub directories

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am trying to redirect a URL to its sub directory. Is it possible to redirect such a url:

https://example.com/subdir/client-panel/

to

https://example.com/panel/

Via .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to your hatches file the redirect will work.

```
# 301 --- https://example.com/subdir/client-panel/ => https://example.com/panel/

RewriteRule ^subdir/client-panel/$ /panel/? [L,R=301]
```